# Calling Webservices in WP7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I am working on Windows Phone 7 platform and want to call the webservices for login, and other details.

But i am not getting the way to call the webserives. Can you please help me about how to call webservice in WP7.

Currently i m using this

```
public string GetXmlResponse(string Url)
{            
    try
    {
        wr = WebRequest.Create(Url);
        hwr = (HttpWebRequest)wr;
        hwr.Method = "GET";
        hwr.ContentType = "text/xml";
        //hwr.Timeout = 2147483647;
        //hwr.ContentLength = URL.Length;
        IAsyncResult ar = null;
        ar = (IAsyncResult)hwr.BeginGetResponse(AsyncResponse, hwr);
    }
    catch
    {
        resp = null;
    }
    return resp;
}
public void AsyncResponse(IAsyncResult ar)
{            
    try
    {
        WebResponse ws = hwr.EndGetResponse(ar);
        StreamReader streader = new StreamReader(ws.GetResponseStream());
        resp = streader.ReadToEnd();
    }
    catch
    {
        resp = null;
    }            
}
```

But as it makes AsyncResponse, it returns me the null value, while calling the function GetXmlResponse.

Please help me for any thing.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By creating the delegate i have handled this.

In AsyncResponse i fire the delegate and on my form that fires the event for me.

This is how i am able to manage this.

i refered [this link](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/C__Events.aspx) to create the delegate.

Thanks
BHAVIK GOYAL

Answer (score 1):

have you checked out the XNA site? http://create.msdn.com/en-US/ 
There is a link that goes to channel 9's Windows phone 7 development tutorials. One of the lessons that is on the second day I believe has a really good video of how to use web services.

Comment: Can you please provide me the link for that video? I am not able to find that video.

Comment: http://channel9.msdn.com/series/windows-phone-7-development-for-absolute-beginners

Answer (score -1):

Try using HttpWebRequest.Create

```
wr = HttpWebRequest.Create(Url);
```

Also if the 'Method' is "GET", ContentType is not required.

Comment: Do you think this is allowed in WP7?